# How to call a non-static method from asp.net code behind using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

Within a web form I have the following jQuery setup to call a method in my code behind file.

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#newBtn").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AJAXCaller.aspx/GetTimer",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    cache: false

                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <a href="#" class="link1" runat="server">Click here</a><br /><br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="newBtn" runat="server" Text="ASP Link" />
    <asp:Label ID="time_lbl" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And within the code behind I have the following:

```
[WebMethod]
        public void GetTimer()
        {
            time_lbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

I realize this currently does not work in the current syntax.

I've been able to access the method if I set it to static however I don't want to just return a string or single value. I want to access a method that in turn access a web service to return a collection of data.

I would like to know if it is possible to perform something like this where I can call a method and have it update a field in the UI such as the above method where when called the server side script would to the ui a value for the date field?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You can update an Asp.Net HiddenField with a returned value from a WebMethod, and then you can access it from any other control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not at all possible because you cannot update any field on UI from server side.

Instead of using `WebMethod` in aspx page use Asp.Net webservices instead to write web methods which can be called using `ajax`.

`ajax` method has a success callback where you can grab the service response and then update the UI field by accessing it with appropriate selector.

E.g

```
    $(function () {
        $("#newBtn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AJAXCaller.asmx/GetTimer",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                     $("#ClientIdOftime_lbl").text(data);
                }

            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: @ShankarSngoli Thank you. However what if I want to update more than a field? You mention ui field per my sample however what if I need to reference a method that would return a collection of data in an object that would be bound to a repeater, grid etc?

Comment: You can return any data from the server but you cannot just use it as a datasource to repeater. There is no repeater on the client side it is all mark.

Comment: Would it not be possible within the method that is called on the server to handle the databinding and updating of the UI? What I want to accomplish is call the method have it perform it's tasks and then allow the method to bind and update the controls (via updatepanel). In essence have a ajax event invoke a postback ?

Comment: In that case use ASP.Net `UpdatePanel` don't mix it up with jQuery ajax.